# How to get some certain field only from a recordset?

Tags: mongodb, scala, foursquare, lift

I have this:

```
temp = place where (_.name matches p2) fetch()
```

Now, what i have to do to get just two field of that results? For example `name` and `id`.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With rogue, you can use :

```
.select()
```

In your case :

```
temp = place where (_.name matches p2) select(_.name, _.id) fetch()
```

More example are available here (go to line 174) :
[Rogue QueryTest.scala](https://github.com/foursquare/rogue/blob/master/rogue-lift/src/test/scala/com/foursquare/rogue/QueryTest.scala)

Comment: This is the best solution. But now I can't convert the MongoRecords into JObject :(

temp.map(_.asJValue) //Error: value asJValue is not a member of (org.bson.types.ObjectId, String)

Answer (score 0):

please find below code for getting selected filed in mongodb.

```
db.user.find( { role: 'admin' }, { name: 1, id: 1 } )
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [projection](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/) parameter which can limit the results to specific fields:

```
val q  = MongoDBObject.empty
val fields = MongoDBObject("userid" ->, name" -> 1)
for (x <- mongoColl.find(q, fields)) println(x)
```

Assuming the basic connection and collections are properly referenced, the above code would return only `userId` and `name`.